# Como identificar o número que foi sorteado

Tags: javascript, array, random

Gostaria de saber como obter os valores das variáveis `nipeSorteado` e `faceSorteada` para comparar com resultado que foi apresentado. O resultado da linha 9 ira mostrar os valores correspondentes ao `arrays`. E eu gostaria de saber o valores randômicos que foram gerados antes de entrar no índice do array.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
//arrays que armazenam os nipes e os numeros das cartas
var nipes = ['♥', '♦', '♣', '♠'];
var faces = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K'];

//sorteando valores para os nipes e para as cartas
var nipeSorteado = nipes[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
var faceSorteada = faces[Math.floor(Math.random() * faces.length)];
document.write("<h1>" + faceSorteada + nipeSorteado + "</h1>");
```

Comment: Adicione o código em formato de texto não de imagem para que fique mais fácil alguém lhe ajudar.

Comment: já inseri o código, vlw pela dica.

Answer (score 1):

É simples, basta você receber em variáveis os números randômicos antes de passar como índice da array.

Ao invés de receber direto o valor randômico como índice da array

```
 var nipeSorteado = nipes[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
```

Passe o `Math.floor(..)` para uma variável e depois sete como índice:

```
var numnipe = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
...
..

var nipeSorteado = nipes[numnipe];
```

Ficando o código assim:

```js
    //arrays que armazenam os nipes e os numeros das cartas
    var nipes = ['♥', '♦', '♣', '♠'];
    var faces = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K'];
    
    //sorteando valores para os nipes e para as cartas
    
    //Número gerado para os nipes
    var numnipe = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    
    //Número gerado para as faces
    var numface = Math.floor(Math.random() * faces.length);
    
    //Valores das variaveis que você desejar obter o valor
    console.log(numnipe, numface);
    
    var nipeSorteado = nipes[numnipe];
    var faceSorteada = faces[numface];
    document.write("<h1>" + faceSorteada + nipeSorteado + "</h1>");
    
    
    console.log(faceSorteada,nipeSorteado);
```